# Wifi is not working correctly on Linux Mint 21

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, iwlwifi

I have been having problems with my wifi using Linux Mint 21. It connects but every few minutes it disconnects by its own. On older versions (20.1, 20.2, 20.3) I didn't have this problem. I want to use the newer versions however.

I am going to add some of the commands so you can see my drivers and such.

`inxi -Fxrzc0`

```
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi
    v: iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27 bus-ID: 00:14.3
  IF: wlo1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
  IF: eno2 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-3: Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter type: USB
    driver: r8152 bus-ID: 2-2.4.2:5
  IF: enx00e04c680b6d state: down mac: <filter>
```

**Some of the steps I have taken so far**

- Installed the generic drivers by doing:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-iwlwifi-generic
```

- Unblock wifi by doing:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

What others steps can I take to get my wifi working?